# How to use HTML with Function (mail) for send info Coordinated?

Tags: php, html, email

How to use HTML with Function "mail" for send info Coordinated ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be asking how to send HTML mail using PHP's [`mail()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function.

While you can do so and there's even an example on the manual page, you shouldn't.  You have to manage all the MIME bits yourself, and set the correct headers, and that's a bit of a pain.

Instead, grab a third-party library that does all the dirty work for you, like [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=phpmailer) or [PEAR Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/) or [Zend Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html).  They're all pure-PHP and licensed so that you can simply bundle them with your application without having to get them installed by the sysadmin.